# Handling signals with gdb

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, signals, ubuntu-10.04

I'm debugging a C++ app for Ubuntu 10.04 that sometimes receives a `SIGKILL` signal.
I want to *catch* the signal and stop it from killing the execution, just to see if I can get some useful info of the app's state at that precise moment.

Reading the [gdb documentation](http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_38.html#SEC38) I found the `handle` command, so I tried to apply it to the SIGKILL signal:

```
(gdb) handle SIGKILL stop nopass
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description
SIGKILL       Yes   Yes     No              Killed
```

So, as I understand this correctly:

```
stop
    GDB should stop your program when this signal happens. This implies the print keyword as well. 
print
    GDB should print a message when this signal happens. 
nopass
    GDB should not allow your program to see this signal.
```

once the `SIGKILL` signal is emitted, `gdb` should somehow catch it, print the message, stop the execution and don't let the app kill itself, right?

The problem is that this doesn't happen and the app terminates.

Do you know how could I *catch* the signal?

**Useful Info:**

- The piece of code that is running when the signal is emitted is executed **in another thread.**
- **gdb version:** 4.4.3
- **g++ version:** 7.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From unix *signal(7)* man page:

```
  The  signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.
```

So the debugger can set the handler but that doesn't make any sense. The OS directly performs the needed action. If SIGKILL could be handled from application the OS has no chance to terminate a broken application. For that reason SIGKILL is a bit *special* :-)

Comment: Great. I'll have to find another way of getting the info. Thanks @Klaus, I should have checked the man page from the start and spare you the work.