# Message "During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL" from GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, aix

I'm having trouble debugging a C++ program on AIX built with GNU tools. When the program runs outside the debugger:

```
-bash-4.3$ ./cryptestcwd v
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When the program runs under GDB, the debugger prints the message *`During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.`* and exits:

[image]

An added wrinkle is, this only happens with an [Autotools front-end](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools). It does not happens with our regular GNUmakefile. We supply the same arguments to both Autotools and the GNUmakefile. We are aware Autotools [adds additional options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47315717/608639) and even [adds C files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47315717/608639) to the C++ project, but we have no control over it.

A related question is at [During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16416866/608639), but it does not have useful answers. Two other related questions just state that `SIGKILL` cannot be caught. Also see [Debugging program that catches SIGKILL under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25325847/608639) and [Handling signals with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23826676/608639).

How can I debug the problem further?

Comment: May need to use a tedious "divide and conquer" approach ? #ifdef out half the code, re-compile, run, repeat...

Comment: If you run the program from the shell, without using gdb, do you get different behavior?

Comment: You may be able to make a class with a  constructor that does something meaningless but hard to compile out, force construction of this class as early as possible in the start-up process, and place a breakpoint in this constructor. From there you may be able to step through the pre-`main` code and find the cause of death.

Comment: @Mark - Yes, the issue is present both inside and outside the debugger. Another wrinkle is, we are trying to add an [Autotools front-end](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools). Our regular [hand written] GNUmakefile is fine. The problem only surfaces under the Autotools binaries. And the image above is the Autotools binary.

Comment: So you can easily compare the compile and link commands.

Comment: @RustyX - Well, I'm not sure how easy it will be. We place the same options in Autotools we place in our GNUmakefile. But Autotools adds its own flags and I don't know how to stop them. And Autotools adds C source files to the project, and I don't know how to stop that behavior either. Related, see [How to disable C compiler in C++ Autotools project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47060001/608639). And I think Libtool adding C source files is a bug; see [Bug #29298: C++ compiler, Newlib and "implicit declaration..."](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2017-11/msg00002.html).

Comment: @OP Do examine the core file with gdb.

Answer (score 2):

The `SIGKILL` at startup most likely means that the AIX runtime loader couldn't find some library that the binary links against (a Linux runtime loader produces a more helpful error message when that happens).

You should verify that `ldd cryptestcwd` doesn't complain about anything.

You could also try to load the `core` that is produced when you run your program outside of GDB into GDB -- there may be additional clues there (use `info shared`, `where`, `x/i $pc` commands).

Comment: Actually, unlike linux!loader, AIX!loader does explain what unresolved external prohibited the loading of the program. There is no core-dump in these cases.